# Ruby - finding the first N palindromic prime using lazy evaluation

Tags: ruby, performance

i think my code is correct - yet i do not return an array in time for N = 200. Error is "Terminated due to timeout"
what can i do to improve the performance of this code?

```rb
def is_palindrome? (n)
   n.to_s==n.to_s.reverse
end

def is_prime? (n)
  return false if n< 2
  (2..Math.sqrt(n)).none? {|f| n % f == 0}
end

prime_palindrome =-> (n) do
   1.upto(Float::INFINITY).lazy.select { |n| is_prime?(n) && is_palindrome(n) }.first(n)
end


n = gets.to_i 
p prime_palindrome.call(n)
```

Comment: testing for is_palindrome?(n) first is actually way faster. I managed to avoid timeouts this way.

Comment: Stylistically, `palindrome?` is more in-line with Ruby style than `is_palindrome?`.

Comment: Your problem is that `prime_palindrome.call(n)` returns an enumerator. You need to convert that to an array using [Enumerable#to_a](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-to_a), as @Amadan has done. You could also use [Enumerable#entries](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-entries). You should be using the method [Prime::each](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/prime/rdoc/Prime.html#method-i-each) to generate primes (assuming you are not banned from doing so).

Answer (score 1):

Ruby knows how to do this faster.

```
require 'prime'

Prime.each.lazy.
    select { |p| p.to_s.then { |s| s == s.reverse } }.
    take(200).to_a
```

Answer (score 1):

Lazy enumerators (as used in @Amadan's answer) are useful but seem to have a reputation for being somewhat slow. I thought it might be interesting to do a simple benchmark here, comparing Amadan's answer with a straightforward calculation using a `while` loop.

```
require 'prime'
```

**Lazy enumerator**

```
def amadan(n)
  Prime::EratosthenesSieve.instance.send(:initialize)       
  Prime.each.lazy.
    select { |p| p.to_s.then { |s| s == s.reverse } }.
    take(n).to_a
end
```

**while loop**

```
def cary(n)
  Prime::EratosthenesSieve.instance.send(:initialize)
  arr = []
  enum = Prime.each
  while n > 0
    p = enum.next
    s = p.to_s
    if s == s.reverse
      arr << p
      n -= 1
    end
  end
  arr
end
```

The first line of each method, `Prime::EratosthenesSieve...` is included to make the benchmark more realistic. See the discussion in the comments.

**Benchmark**

```
require 'fruity'
```

#

```
n = 200
compare(amadan: -> { amadan(n) }, cary: -> { cary(n) })

Running each test once. Test will take about 10 seconds.
cary is faster than amadan by 10.000000000000009% ± 1.0%

Results are similar for other values of `n`.
```

Comment: To be fair, OP did ask for it :P "finding the first N palindromic prime _using lazy evaluation_"

Comment: @Amadan, I missed that, but had I not I would have given the same answer. I was just curious about the comparison I reported, and thought it was worth  sharing. In practice I would have gone lazy, if performance was not an issue. Members of the Lazy Coder League, such as I, like lazy methods because they tend to reduce the number of lines of code that are needed.

Comment: The `Prime` class caches calculated prime numbers, so the first test will always be much slower since it is warming the cache. Try running `Prime.each.take(120_000)` before `compare`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland `Prime.each.take(120_000)` is for `n = 200` – it just pre-calculates the primes used in the tests. The 200th palindromic prime (`cary(200).last`) is `1469641` and `Prime.each.take(120_000).last` returns `1583539`,  thus covering the test range.

Comment: @Stefan, no change (still `"...60.00000000000001% ± 10.0%"`). On my laptop `Prime.each.take(120_000)` takes well under 1 second and the benchmark takes 3 seconds for one test, so I'm not surprised.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Warming the cache was not the correct approach – it effectively removes the prime calculation from the benchmark, leaving just lazy vs. non-lazy enumeration. To get comparable results, you'd have to _reset_ the cache beforehand. Try running `Prime::EratosthenesSieve.instance.send(:initialize)` before both, `amadan(n)` and `cary(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

You just forgot the **question mark "?"** in the first code you wrote. If we add it, your code will work, but using Prime is a more logical and faster solution.

```rb
def is_palindrome? (n)
    n.to_s==n.to_s.reverse
 end
 
 def is_prime? (n)
   return false if n< 2
   (2..Math.sqrt(n)).none? {|f| n % f == 0}
 end
 
 prime_palindrome =-> (n) do
    1.upto(Float::INFINITY).lazy.select { |n| is_prime?(n) && is_palindrome?(n) }.first(n)
 end
 
 
 n = gets.to_i 
 p prime_palindrome.call(n)
```